# redirecting to a different page in POST call (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a post request in jquery. It sends an XHR request and it gets completed successfully. However, I also want to redirect it to a different page when that request is triggered.

this is my code:

```
$(".checkout-button").click(function(){
    $.post("{% url 'book:booking' %}", seat_total, function(response){});
           });
```

this is my button to which this is linked

```
<button class="checkout-button">Checkout &raquo;</button>
```

How can I redirect it to this url -- {% url 'book:booking' %}

Comment: use window.location.href

Comment: So you don't need the request result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific solution to your question:

```
$(".checkout-button").click(function(){
    $.post(
        "{% url 'book:booking' %}", 
        seat_total, 
        function (response) {
            window.location.href = "{% url 'book:booking' %}"
        }
    );
});
```

General answers how to redirect with JavaScript: [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

the callback doesn't do anything fancy to the code within it just changes when that code is executed.

Just add this line:

`window.location.href = http://www.google.com;`

and replace google with your link